# Is virtualized Linux fast enough for software development?

Tags: linux, development-environment, virtualization

I've got a reasonably pumped processor (Core 2 Quad) benching around 1/3rd of the best money can buy, 4GB RAM, yet I can't seem to strike a Linux distro/virtualization combo that simply is responsive enough for typical development work.

For example, the cursor motion in IntelliJ IDEA is simply not consistent and responsive enough to move and edit accurately.

Flipping over to a running Firefox takes a few seconds, even switching between tabs in Firefox isn't instant.

In the host O/S, Windows 7, app switches, tab switches etc everything happens instantly.

I've tried Ubuntu and Kubuntu 11.04. I've tried VirtualBox and VMWare.  All had very different responses. None good enough.

I've played around with RAM settings etc and maybe there's some config setting I missing. I'm not trying to find the cause here on SO, but I would just first like to know if I have my head in the clouds thinking I can develop on virtualized Linux at the speed I did in Windows?

The distros I tried, especially Ubuntu, looked like they'd been dumbed down for the general user. Do I need to find an older distro, or something a bit rawer? I only want a desktop to hold multiple windows, run apps from and look graphically pleasant. No bloatware or fancy effects (or LCD clocks ahhhh...)

Or does virtualization just require the ultimate in hardware? I've just switched over to Linux with very little knowledge of it and have no idea if it's the virtualization, my machine or simply the distros I've tried.

**Update**

I fiddled around some more but as soon as a second app was on screen, response suffered. Also when the display was made to span two monitors, even a single app suffered. I will get some more RAM, even though I still had some physical memory left when running two apps.

I thought I'd give an XFCE distro a go (Xubuntu) and the thing flies, no response issues at all, plus I'm happy with it being minimal.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your configuration, or maybe you graphics hardware. I have used virtualized ubuntu and it is as fast as native install

Comment: My guess is that your Windows 7 is not optimized for running VM guests. Also I suspect that 4Gb is horribly little memory given the host OS. My personal experience is that for some reason, guest OSs are nearly unusable if __outlook is running__ on the host.

Comment: That's good to hear zad (although I don't know how fast a native install runs but I assume fast).

Comment: @Kimvais, maybe RAM is the issue given that the responses so far suggest virtualized is fast enough for development. I might pop a question on superuser as I look at my memory usage now and 1.4GB of the 1.5GB physical memory I've now allocated to the guest is being used just running the base system, Firefox, IDEA, python and mysql. No Outlook running, OneNote is the only MS app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work everyday on a Linux (Centos) VM running within VMWare Workstation on the following setups:

- Quad Core 2 Duo 8G of RAM
- Intel i7 with 16G of RAM

With those setups, I typically give the VM 2 of my 4 cores and 2-4G of RAM.  You likely don't need to give them that much.  I use Eclipse as my IDE and run in Unity Mode most of the time without issue.

I've never had problems so I'm not certain that the suggestions below make any noticeable difference but try the follwing, which should help to increase the performance of your virtual machines:

- If using VMWare be sure to install VMWare Tools.
- Check your BIOS settings to see if you have Virtualization Extensions turned on for your processor.
- Increase the priority on your Virtualization software.

Good luck!

Comment: What OS is your host on those setups?  The first machine is getting closer to my specs plus Eclipse being Java as well. I assume when you're in Eclipse, if you hold down the right arrow key you'll see the cursor move through every character, not jump groups of characters?

 VMWare Tools is installed. Increasing priority of VMWare to high didn't make any noticable changes. I'll have a look at BIOS soon.

Comment: I'm running on Windows 7 Professional.  Yes, Eclipse is very responsive and the cursor will move through all characters one by one just as you would expect in a native setup.

Answer (score 3):

Did you install the guest tools (which includes paravirtualized drivers) when you tried it? The VMware tools are essential for a good experience. I do this all the time, except I just edit text with Vim so performance has never been a problem.

Comment: Yes, I had installed guest tools in both. VMWare was noticeably more responsive for me than VirtualBox. I get perfect performance in Vim too, but not the Java-based IDEA. Dual monitor much better response when both showing Linux rather than one Windows, one Linux as one would imagine.

Answer (score 2):

You should be perfectly fine with VirtualBox *and Guest Additions installed in the guest OS*.
Ubuntu is user friendly, and if you want it without the bloatware consider installing Ubuntu server.

Actually almost every linux distro has a server version which is usually the bloat-less version.

Comment: I will look at Ubuntu server thanks for the heads up. I'd just assumed it wouldn't have a GUI but it looks like it does.

Comment: @stebbo: IIRC it gives you an option whether to install the GUI (X11 and related packages). Of course you can always add things on once you have it running.